# Why my environmental variable is returning undefined using parcel and react

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, parceljs

I am working on a project in React and Parcel when I try console.log(process.env) is returning an empty object but if I add API_Key to it  will return undefined

Can someone tell me what is wrong? Why my environmental variable is returning undefined

here is my package json :

```
"scripts": {
    "clear-build-cache": "rm -rf .cache/ dist/",
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html",
    "dev:mock": "cross-env OPEN-INV=mock parcel src/index.html",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

here is my .env file which is next to the package .json
REACT_APP_API_KEY:"my api key"

```
console.log(process.env) // {}
console.log(process.env. REACT_APP_API_Key)// undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues.

## 1. Change .env variable name, value declarations

Environment file, `.env` requires value & name in `NAME=VALUE` format.

So instead of

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY:"my api key"
```

You need to do

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=MyAPIKey
```

Refer to the [.env USAGE documentation](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#usage) pointed from [Parcel .env documentation](https://parceljs.org/env.html), which uses dotenv

## 2. You need to refer to the environment variable exact the way you declared.

As [pointed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57224399/4035) by @Emanuele,

You need to refer to the environment variable name exactly the way it's declared.
So instead of

```
process.env. REACT_APP_API_Key
```

Refer to the value as

```
process.env. REACT_APP_API_KEY
```

---

---

---

---

---

---

## * Update: Using [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) * to configure environment variables

As you are using Parcel, you need to manually load the environment variable, using `dotenv`. (`create-react-app` automatically handles this).

After installing `dotenv`, you need to call [config()](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#config) to parse the `.env` file to be able to use it as `process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY`.

Refer to the sample code below

**.env**

```sh
REACT_APP_API_KEY=API key from .env file
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

function App() {
  console.log(`process.env`, process.env);
  return <h1>{process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}</h1>;
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

You can see the console output & the header shown using the environment variable value.

[image: working demo]

You can follow the demo in the Sandbox.
[image: Edit so.answer.57224268]

*The sandbox uses `parceljs`.*

Comment: Hi Sung, Thank you for replying back.
Even by changing .env o this REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'my key' the process.env.REACT_APP_KEY is returning undefined!!!

Comment: @nik.ss I am sorry I misunderstood you were using `create-react-app`, which automatically imports `.env` files. Parcel doesn't import `.env` automatically AFAIK. So I updated the answer, which uses `dotenv` and a demo program.

Comment: Hi Sung, 
That makes sense. I am actually using react not the create-react-app so I changed my .env from REACT_APP_API_KEY to just API_KEY and it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great job @nik.ss. Glad you were able to find the answer yourself 

Answer (score 3):

Another use case that can cause this issue is `package.json` or even `package-lock.json` up the folder tree. Parcel will for some reason load environment variables from the top-most `package.json` file it can find.

So check your folder structure and make sure there are no `package.json` or `package-lock.json` files above your project folder.

Comment: This was the solution for me since I'm working in a monorepo with many `package.json` files.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you using `REACT_APP_API_Key` instead of `REACT_APP_API_KEY`? Maybe it is the problem.